# Why the "begin/end" vs "first/last" discrepancy?

Tags: c++

Why do containers offer "`begin`"/"`end`" iterators while algorithms want "`first`"/"`last`" iterators?

For example:

- `vector` offers `.begin()` and `.end()` ([cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)).
- `sort` wants parameters `first` and `last` ([cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)).

**Edit:** Found an even bigger discrepancy. It's not just *algorithms* that use "`first`/`last`", it's also **container constructors** (like [`vector(first, last, ...)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)).

I didn't check *all* containers and algorithms, but did check a few more and all containers offered `begin`/`end` and all algorithms wanted `first`/`last` (or variations like `first1` and `first2`).

Is there a good reason for this? To me it would make more sense if they all used the same. Preferably `begin` and `end`, as I dislike `last` because that sounds inclusive but isn't. For algorithms it would simply mean the begin and end of the range to be processed, just like what first and last mean now.

Comment: Note that `first` and `last` can be any two iterators as long as `last` is "after" `first`. They do **not** have to be the beginning and ending of an actual container. They can be **anything**.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: `first` and `last` can also be equal.

Comment: The wording in the standard is a bit inconsistent anyway. For example, §24.2.1/8 [iterator.requirements.general] says: *"Most of the library’s algorithmic templates that operate on data structures have interfaces that use ranges. A range is a pair of iterators that designate the beginning and end of the computation."*

Comment: `first` and `last` are parameters, `begin()` and `end()` are arguments

Comment: @M.M What does that matter?

Comment: begin and start are synonyms in English.  Similarly end and last are synonyms.   The reasoning was probably that they wanted member function names (`begin()` and `end()`) and names of function parameters (first and last) to be distinct.  Giving distinct things the same name - even if they are related - tends to make code harder for mere mortals to understand (which is one reason for various guidelines that functions with the same name do related things).

Comment: @Peter I don't think "end" and "last" are synonyms. To me, "last" is clearly inclusive while "end" can be either inclusive or exclusive. "last" sounds like an element, but "end" can also be a "border". Yes, members and parameters are different things, but these are so related that I think it would be *better* if they were called the same. I'd love to be asked for a "begin" and "end" and indeed *literally* provide a "begin" and "end". Would be a perfect fit.

Comment: There are multiple similar but distinct meanings of all the words (and they are adverbs, adjectives, nouns, ... depending on context too).   Look up first in a thesaurus, and begin will turn up (and vice versa).   Similarly with end and last (which also show up as antonyms of begin and first).

Comment: There are also many other related pairs of words that could have been used:  head and tail, opening and ending, leader and terminator, anterior and posterior, top and bottom, etc.     Some of those, admittedly, would be perverse (and annoying to type) so be glad those weren't picked.

Comment: The names of parameters don't actually matter to C++ and are just a way to document things in each manual or in a header file (the names you use in a header could even be different than the .cpp file). For a good example, look up the function 'strstr' in various manuals. Cppreference calls the parameters using the generic names 'str' for the string to be searched and 'target' for the string you are searching for, whereas other manuals refer to these parameters as 'haystack' and 'needle', respectively. The point is that the names don't really matter as long as the use is clear.

Comment: @Brandin: Technically true; however, the parameter names *do* appear in the ISO standard document itself, which certainly lends them an official enough quality. As far as I am aware, cppreference.com just uses the same names as in the standard, which makes sense.

Comment: @Brandin: The same goes for the C standard, where `strstr` is documented in §7.24.5.7 (at least in my n1570 draft here) as `char *strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2);`. Now I just had a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr, and they indeed call the parameters `str` and `substr` there, which IMO is a bad idea. Perhaps cppreference.com just is a bit sloppy with C functions.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Giving parameters distinguishable names makes it easier to teach how to use it, the aim of a manual like Cppreference. The Standard's aim, however, is not to be 'teachable', but to be a standard.

Comment: @Brandin But using the same names makes it easier to see connections...

Comment: @Brandin: That doesn't sound right. If it was, all parameter names in all functions defined in the standard would just be `param1`, `param2` and so on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is likely to be historical: this is what they were called by Stepanov and Lee, first implementers of STL, which later evolved into C++ Standard Library.

Here is [Stepanov's paper on STL](http://stepanovpapers.com/STL/DOC.PDF). Page 47 describes sort

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator>
void sort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last);
```

Page 19 describes containers' operations `begin()` and `end()`.

Note that in addition to `begin`/`first` and `end`/`last` C++ Standard Library describes optional sequence operations `front()` and `back()`. The difference in naming is easy to understand here, because the operations must be available on the same container, and `back()` is inclusive.

Comment: Thanks. Though now the question is why Stepanov and Lee did it. I'll have a look at that paper. `front` and `back` I'd say are something different, not just because `back` is inclusive but mostly because they're references, not iterators.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I doubt that they were thinking much about consistency at the time they were writing their implementation, because it was a research project to them. The proposal to make it part of C++ standard happened only in 1993, many years into their research. I am sure that the popularity of their library has surpassed their wildest expectations.

Comment: Well like I said, they actually seem to be quite consistent, containers always offering "begin"/"end" and algorithms always wanting "first"/"last". So I thought there must be a reason for that. And I just realized that even container constructors always want "first"/"last". There goes my theory that Stepanov did containers and Lee did algorithms and after a while they met again and both said *"You called them what? I'm not gonna change now. You change yours."*

Comment: Ooh, maybe that's actually a reason. If container constructors (and methods like `erase(first, last)` called their parameters `begin` and `end`, then they couldn't access the container's own `begin` and `end` anymore (at least not just by those names).

Comment: (I didn't find a reasoning in the paper, btw, but came across the container constructur/method thing while searching there.)

Comment: @StefanPochmann: That sounds more like a problem than it actually is. You can easily give parameters the same name as a member function and there will be virtually no conflicts. If there is one, it's easy to disambiguate (e.g. via `this->begin()`).

Comment: @ChristianHackl Yes, that's what I meant with "at least not just by those names". Also, `this->` doesn't appear anywhere in that paper. Are you sure they had that available back then?

Comment: @StefanPochmann: You may have a point there; after all, the STL or rather its precursor was originally implemented in Ada, not in C++, and who knows what the naming rules are there (I don't).

Answer (score 10):

`first` and `last` can be any two iterators as long as `last` is not "before" `first`. They do **not** have to be the beginning and ending of a container.

Comment: Yes, I know. But that doesn't explain why they're not called `begin` and `end`.

Comment: Probably that's the idea, but they still are the begin and the end of the *range* that is processed, just as `begin` and `end` return the begin and end of the *range* that represents the whole container. It seems that indeed the library authors apply the terms `first` and `last` to ranges and `begin` and `end` to containers.

Comment: As I said above, `last` can also be equal to `first`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Just as `begin` can be equal to `end` in an empty container. But likely you are refering to "as long as last is after first" in the answer, in that case your clarification is justified.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher: Yes. It should be "as long as last is not before first".

Comment: @ChristianHackl Thanks for suggested change to my wording.

Comment: @ChristianHackl "as long as last is not before first" comes with its own share of problems, because `last` and `first` might not be unordered with regards to each other (not pointing into the same sequence). Of course they don't represent a valid range is this case. But in this case I can say that `last` is not `before` first as well as `last` is not after `first`, too. So it should read `last` is the same as or after `first`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Calling the function parameters `begin/end` would incorrectly suggest that you can only pass the return values of `Container::begin()` and `Container::end()`.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher: *"Of course they don't represent a valid range is this case."* - in which case the behaviour is undefined and the terminology question becomes moot, IMHO.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher bleh...I'm too tired to get all grammar nazi on my own answer right now. Feel free to edit if you would like.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Some programmers like to import the std namespace (using namespace std), so if you called a variable or parameter 'begin' or 'end', then it would not be as clear to a human whether by 'begin' you mean 'std::begin' or the local 'begin' variable that you just declared in the parameter list.

Comment: @Brandin That could be an argument *now*, but I think `std::begin` and `std::end` were only introduced in C++11 and the begin/end/first/last naming scheme is far older than that (see the paper from 1995 mentioned in dasblinkenlight's answer).

Comment: @StefanPochmann: but internally, (for example for `std::vector::erase(iterator front, iterator last)`) comparing `last` with `end()` might be less confusing than comparing `end` with `end()`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah, maybe. I mentioned something similar under dasblinkenlight's answer (also using `erase` as an example). Maybe the distinction wasn't even possible in the language they were using back then. And even if it was, maybe they were thinking the STL might get implemented in other languages as well and wanted to be cautious.

Answer (score 5):

Imho it would be even more confusing if containers and algorithms would name them in the same way. The whole point of algorithms taking iterators is that they need not to be the `begin` and `end` of a container, but they can be any iterators. Having different names on the interfaces emphazises the fact that you as user are responsible for passing a meaningful pair of `first` and `last` iterator.

On the other hand, it is a weak point of algorithms that they offer no methods taking a container as parameter, when in most cases you simply want the algorithm to work from `begin` to `end` of an iterator.

Comment: Hmm, I wouldn't find it confusing. Yes, `begin` and `end` don't need to be those of a whole *container*, but like I said, I'd simply understand them to mean the beginning and end of a *range*, and I'd find that quite neat. But yeah, maybe it's supposed to emphasize the decoupling. At least that's the only potential reason I've seen so far.

Comment: @StefanPochmann you can also pass reverse iterators to algorithms, in which case `first` and `last` are the first and last iterators processed by the algorithm, but they are not the `begin` and `end` of a range (rather `end` end `begin`). For such cases I find it important to make a distinction between what is the begin and end of a container and what is the first and last processed by the algorithm

Comment: In such cases they still **are** the begin and end of a range. Simply of that reverse range. I don't see a problem with that. Also, when you say "last processed", I find *that* misleading, as "last" is exclusive and thus what it points to *isn't* processed.

Comment: @StefanPochmann well of course the opinions on what is confusin can differ widely. Anyway I wonder why this wasnt closed for beeing too opinion-based :P

Comment: @StefanPochmann it is always difficult to answer why something was made like it is. Only those sitting in the comitee can know the real reason, and we just have to accept the way it is. Often there is no deeper meaning to it other than "Thats the way it was decided"

Comment: Well this isn't about opinions. I'm not asking what people prefer. I'm asking why the names are what they are.

Comment: @tobi303: It would be opinion-based if it asked whether "begin" or "start" was better. But it does not. It's asking for a reason for something, and if that *reason* turns out to be opinion-based, then that doesn't make the question opinion-based.

Comment: @ChristianHackl as I understand the close reason it also covers question that are completely fine, if the "[..] answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise." And speaking for myself, my answer reflect just my opinion, but I have no evidence of why it was decided that way. Nevermind, I wouldnt vote to close this one

Comment: @tobi303: That Stepanov and Lee just made an opinion-based choice **is** a fact. Stating that fact is not an opinion.

Comment: @ChristianHackl good point. Completely agree.